# We're not a bank, get rid of [audit] (or replace it with less ambiguous tags)

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[audit](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audit) isn't useful as it refers to a whole bunch of different topics, including license auditing, security auditing, and software auditing.

Can we get rid of it, or perhaps retag questions with less ambiguous tags?

Comment: I don't see the issue.  Audit refers to a specific process / subject area.  It looks like all of the questions do relate to a single understanding/definition of auditing (it hasn't been applied to a wide variety of topics, just auditing of different things).  The Linux tag, for example, applies to everything under the sun, but it serves an important purpose.  The Printing tag could apply to different kinds of printers, different kinds of printer issues, printing all different kinds of things, but they all refer to the same process.  More specialized replacement tags wouldn't buy anything.

Comment: @fixer1234 that's precisely the issue I see, it depends on other tags for context, thus, can't be the only tag on the question.

Comment: @Braiam: Meta tags get into a grey area.  Something like a manufacturer tag, when the manufacturer makes everything imaginable, provides no clue on its own.  An OS tag is maybe a special case, but that, alone, tells you nothing about a question.  It's a clarifier.  I think there's a need for process tags that serve a similar function.  Used in combination with other tags, they add useful information or focus.  There are very few tags that are really adequate as the only tag.  I have nothing against spinning off a collection of more specific audit tags, just don't see an issue with it as-is.

Comment: @fixer1234 if I favorite any of them, I would be thrown a pile of crap that I may or may not be able to answer at all. I prefer tags to be the minimun common denominator between a bunch of questions, rather than whatever you could categorize them also. Remember, tags are for answerers, a tag that doesn't help your question to be answered may as well be removed.

Comment: @Braiam: I can see where broad tags might not be useful to favorite.  You'd have to use them in a different way, like in a multi-tag search, or favorite a broader topic (like [security] in this example), and then scan the results for the [audit] tag, or look at the tag combinations in the active questions list.  Looking at the 53 questions, some of them probably weren't helped by the tag, but we can't assume people haven't been using the tag as-is to help spot questions.  I don't think we should just trash the tag, but agree it could be more efficient to use by breaking out sub-topic tags.

Answer (score 7):

["Auditing" is the actual name of a Windows feature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc960594.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) so eliminating the tag is not an option.

Your proposal may get disambiguation traction if you actually propose some alternate tag names, instead of merely asking to "get rid of it".

Comment: This seems to go in hand with group policies which already has a tag, and going by the kind of questions that this tag gets, none has anything to do with Group Policies.